# Read Text File in jQuery and check if it is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text file on a server that I can read out by:

```
jQuery.get("oben.txt",function(txt){
$("#output-head").text(txt);
});
```

I can write it in the Webpage itself.
What I want to do is to check if the File String inside the Text File is empty or not.

in another Javascript file I try to check if the Element got a String, I tried it already with classes and ID´s, by checking it´s length and it´s value but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: `if (txt.trim() == '')`

Answer (score 0):

Can use

```
$.ajax({
        url : "oben.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            if(data != ''){
                $("#output-head").html(data);
            }

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **txt.trim().length** as shown here:

```
jQuery.get("open.txt",function(txt){
    $("#output-head").text(txt);
    if(txt.trim().length > 0){
        console.log(txt.trim().length)
    }
});
```